# Preparation of alkyl halide from alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

$\ce{R-OH + HBr -> R-Br + H2O}$

An $\ce{R+}$ carbocation is formed during this reaction.

If $\ce{R}$ is any alkyl group instead of methyl or ethyl, can the [beta hydrogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_and_beta_carbon) to the hydroxy group be removed to form a double bond, similar to a dehydration??

Answer (score 5):

It can happen.

It practice, you avoid it happening by keeping the temperature low. $\ce{Br-}$ is a better nucleophile than $\ce{H2O}$ is a base, so at lower temperatures, the substitution is faster.

If the elimination happens, alkenes react with $\ce{HBr}$ to form alkyl bromides. As long as acid is present, the carbocation can reform. For example, with isopropyl alcohol

**Direct S<sub>N</sub>1 Substitution** 
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH-OH + HBr -> (CH3)2CH-OH2+ + Br-}$$
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH-OH2+ -> (CH3)2CH+ + H2O}$$
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH+ + Br- -> (CH3)2CH-Br}$$

**Substitution by elimination-addition**
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH-OH + HBr -> (CH3)2CH-OH2+ + Br-}$$
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH-OH2+ -> (CH3)2CH+ + H2O}$$
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH+ + H2O <=> CH3-CH=CH2 + H3O+}$$
$$\ce{(CH3)2CH+ + Br- -> (CH3)2CH-Br}$$

In some cases, two processes may appear to generate different alkyl halides, but this would be no different than if a carbocation rearrangement occurred.